# Display column families and column qualifiers through hbase shell command

Tags: java, hbase, mapr

I am having millions of rows in HBASE which contains runtime column qualifiers which is countable(ie which is less than 10). It is difficult to scan the entire the rows in HBASE table. Is there any way to print the column qualifiers in column family through hbase shell or any utilities available to print?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of predefined utility as such till now. May be you can use the below code to get the column qualifiers for a column family within a table.

Usage : HbaseCqIdentifier [tableName] [columnFamily]

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Admin;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Connection;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultScanner;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Table;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;

public class HbaseCqIdentifier {
    private static Connection conn;
    private static Set<byte[]> columnQualifiers;

    public static Admin getConnection() throws IOException {
        if (conn == null) {
            conn = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(HBaseConfiguration.create());
        }
        return conn.getAdmin();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        getConnection();
        scan(args[0], args[1]);
        columnQualifiers.forEach((k) -> System.out.println("Column Qualifier : " + Bytes.toString(k)));
    }

    public static void scan(String tableName, String columnFamily) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Table Name : " + tableName);
        Table table = conn.getTable(TableName.valueOf(tableName));
        Scan scan = new Scan();
        scan.addFamily(Bytes.toBytes(columnFamily));
        ResultScanner rs = table.getScanner(scan);

        while(rs.iterator().hasNext()){
            rs.forEach((k)-> columnQualifiers = k.getFamilyMap(Bytes.toBytes(columnFamily)).keySet());
        }
    }
}
```

**Note: Add hadoop and hbase jars along with hbase-site.xml in classpath**